# I get this error while running a python script that loads weights: "UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm." Using tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using this [Yolo Detection algorithm](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2) implemented in Tensorflow 2.0

I am trying to run the convert.py script to convert weights from .weights to .tf format

```
from absl import app, flags, logging
from absl.flags import FLAGS
import numpy as np
from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
from yolov3_tf2.utils import load_darknet_weights

flags.DEFINE_string('weights', './data/yolov3.weights', 'path to weights file')
flags.DEFINE_string('output', './checkpoints/yolov3.tf', 'path to output')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('tiny', False, 'yolov3 or yolov3-tiny')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_classes', 80, 'number of classes in the model')


def main(_argv):
    if FLAGS.tiny:
        yolo = YoloV3Tiny(classes=FLAGS.num_classes)
    else:
        yolo = YoloV3(classes=FLAGS.num_classes)
    yolo.summary()
    logging.info('model created')

    load_darknet_weights(yolo, FLAGS.weights, FLAGS.tiny)
#     load_darknet_weights(yolo, FLAGS.wt, FLAGS.tiny)
    logging.info('weights loaded')

    img = np.random.random((1, 320, 320, 3)).astype(np.float32)
    output = yolo(img)
    logging.info('sanity check passed')

    yolo.save_weights(FLAGS.output)
#     yolo.save_weights(FLAGS.output_filename)
    logging.info('weights saved')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(main)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

When i run the script on my laptop, i get the following output

```
2020-04-21 16:46:45.681070: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:47.958272: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.025611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.455GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2020-04-21 16:46:48.035258: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.051465: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.068787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.083577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.103667: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.118779: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.129332: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.134974: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-21 16:46:48.150660: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-04-21 16:46:48.169252: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.455GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2020-04-21 16:46:48.217485: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.233542: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.251048: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.267639: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.284105: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.302952: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.307620: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:48.312063: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-21 16:46:48.903453: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-21 16:46:48.907725: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2020-04-21 16:46:48.910132: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-21 16:46:48.913759: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4625 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
Model: "yolov3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input (InputLayer)              [(None, None, None,  0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_darknet (Model)            ((None, None, None,  40620640    input[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_conv_0 (Model)             (None, None, None, 5 11024384    yolo_darknet[1][2]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_conv_1 (Model)             (None, None, None, 2 2957312     yolo_conv_0[1][0]
                                                                 yolo_darknet[1][1]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_conv_2 (Model)             (None, None, None, 1 741376      yolo_conv_1[1][0]
                                                                 yolo_darknet[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_output_0 (Model)           (None, None, None, 3 4984063     yolo_conv_0[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_output_1 (Model)           (None, None, None, 3 1312511     yolo_conv_1[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_output_2 (Model)           (None, None, None, 3 361471      yolo_conv_2[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_boxes_0 (Lambda)           ((None, None, None,  0           yolo_output_0[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_boxes_1 (Lambda)           ((None, None, None,  0           yolo_output_1[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_boxes_2 (Lambda)           ((None, None, None,  0           yolo_output_2[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
yolo_nms (Lambda)               ((None, 100, 4), (No 0           yolo_boxes_0[0][0]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_0[0][1]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_0[0][2]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_1[0][0]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_1[0][1]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_1[0][2]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_2[0][0]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_2[0][1]
                                                                 yolo_boxes_2[0][2]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 62,001,757
Trainable params: 61,949,149
Non-trainable params: 52,608
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
I0421 16:46:53.511687  7692 convert.py:21] model created
I0421 16:46:53.514680  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d bn
I0421 16:46:53.517700  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_1 bn
I0421 16:46:53.530661  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_2 bn
I0421 16:46:53.533628  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_3 bn
I0421 16:46:53.547615  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_4 bn
I0421 16:46:53.551580  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_5 bn
I0421 16:46:53.564546  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_6 bn
I0421 16:46:53.568559  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_7 bn
I0421 16:46:53.580528  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_8 bn
I0421 16:46:53.584522  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_9 bn
I0421 16:46:53.598479  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_10 bn
I0421 16:46:53.602474  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_11 bn
I0421 16:46:53.616407  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_12 bn
I0421 16:46:53.630397  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_13 bn
I0421 16:46:53.635380  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_14 bn
I0421 16:46:53.647325  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_15 bn
I0421 16:46:53.652336  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_16 bn
I0421 16:46:53.664281  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_17 bn
I0421 16:46:53.669266  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_18 bn
I0421 16:46:53.681234  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_19 bn
I0421 16:46:53.687243  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_20 bn
I0421 16:46:53.697191  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_21 bn
I0421 16:46:53.702178  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_22 bn
I0421 16:46:53.714170  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_23 bn
I0421 16:46:53.720129  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_24 bn
I0421 16:46:53.731101  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_25 bn
I0421 16:46:53.736087  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_26 bn
I0421 16:46:53.755036  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_27 bn
I0421 16:46:53.765041  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_28 bn
I0421 16:46:53.775980  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_29 bn
I0421 16:46:53.781988  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_30 bn
I0421 16:46:53.793952  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_31 bn
I0421 16:46:53.799940  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_32 bn
I0421 16:46:53.819887  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_33 bn
I0421 16:46:53.831850  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_34 bn
I0421 16:46:53.842825  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_35 bn
I0421 16:46:53.848804  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_36 bn
I0421 16:46:53.859784  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_37 bn
I0421 16:46:53.865765  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_38 bn
I0421 16:46:53.876735  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_39 bn
I0421 16:46:53.882719  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_40 bn
I0421 16:46:53.893665  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_41 bn
I0421 16:46:53.899650  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_42 bn
I0421 16:46:53.910621  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_43 bn
I0421 16:46:53.960506  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_44 bn
I0421 16:46:53.967488  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_45 bn
I0421 16:46:54.016338  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_46 bn
I0421 16:46:54.023343  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_47 bn
I0421 16:46:54.067225  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_48 bn
I0421 16:46:54.074206  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_49 bn
I0421 16:46:54.117069  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_50 bn
I0421 16:46:54.125071  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_darknet/conv2d_51 bn
I0421 16:46:54.166959  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_0/conv2d_52 bn
I0421 16:46:54.172919  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_0/conv2d_53 bn
I0421 16:46:54.215805  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_0/conv2d_54 bn
I0421 16:46:54.221789  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_0/conv2d_55 bn
I0421 16:46:54.263677  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_0/conv2d_56 bn
I0421 16:46:54.269665  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_0/conv2d_57 bn
I0421 16:46:54.321522  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_0/conv2d_58 bias
I0421 16:46:54.324538  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_59 bn
I0421 16:46:54.327506  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_60 bn
I0421 16:46:54.330498  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_61 bn
I0421 16:46:54.339508  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_62 bn
I0421 16:46:54.347453  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_63 bn
I0421 16:46:54.357426  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_1/conv2d_64 bn
I0421 16:46:54.364408  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_1/conv2d_65 bn
I0421 16:46:54.374409  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_1/conv2d_66 bias
I0421 16:46:54.380397  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_67 bn
I0421 16:46:54.383357  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_68 bn
I0421 16:46:54.396343  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_69 bn
I0421 16:46:54.399317  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_70 bn
I0421 16:46:54.402306  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_71 bn
I0421 16:46:54.415271  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_conv_2/conv2d_72 bn
I0421 16:46:54.417288  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_2/conv2d_73 bn
I0421 16:46:54.431258  7692 utils.py:45] yolo_output_2/conv2d_74 bias
I0421 16:46:54.433224  7692 convert.py:25] weights loaded
2020-04-21 16:46:54.443001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-21 16:46:55.716602: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-04-21 16:46:55.722356: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\convert.py", line 38, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\convert.py", line 28, in main
    output = yolo(img)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 822, in __call__     
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 717, in call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 891, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 822, in __call__     
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 717, in call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 891, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 822, in __call__     
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 209, in call      
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1135, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 640, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 239, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2011, in conv2d
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 933, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1022, in conv2d_eager_fallback
    ctx=ctx, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]
```

As you can see, the weights are loaded up, but the sanity check fails..

I have installed:-

tensorflow v2.1.0,

CUDA 10.1,

CUDNN_MAJOR 7
CUDNN_MINOR 6
CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution!

Credit to the users on this [post](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2/issues/64)

> I make the changes in convert.py:
>
> At the beginning of the file:
>
> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> ```
>
> At the end of the file:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
>     try:
>         tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
>         app.run(main)
>     except SystemExit:
>         pass
> ```